# Com port max speed

Tags: c#, serial-port, port

I have a hardware that send data to the com port in the form: "HxxxxVxxxx" where x = number: eg: (H1234V5678).

I want to ask, what should I set the sample rate to send it as soon as possible. (baud 9600, 8bits, parity: none, stop bit: 1).
The program written in Java or C# was able to recive these data on the whole, not in parts.

When sending data every 22ms, and receive such data:

```
2014-08-11 18:48:39.669  56 36 36 37 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.674  48 30 0D 0A 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.687  56 36 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.692  36 39 48 30 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.696  0D 0A 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.712  56 36 36 38 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.716  48 30 0D 0A 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.732  56 36 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.737  36 37 48 30 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.742  0D 0A 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.753  56
```

but i wana somethink like:

```
2014-08-11 18:48:39.600  56 36 36 37 48 30 0D 0A 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.622  56 36 36 37 48 30 0D 0A 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.644  56 36 36 37 48 30 0D 0A 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.666  56 36 36 37 48 30 0D 0A 
2014-08-11 18:48:39.688  56 36 36 37 48 30 0D 0A
```

c# code:

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
    int bytes = comport.BytesToRead;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
    comport.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);

    File.AppendAllText(@"c:\file.txt", timestamp + "  "+ByteArrayToHexString(buffer) +"\n" + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the data you're receiving is in a slightly different format than: "HxxxxVxxxx"

The way I read your logs, you're receiving "V66H0\r\n".
(\r = carriage return, \n = line feed)

If you can guarantee that all of your individual commands will end in a \r\n (0x0D,0x0A), then you have 2 options:

1. Create a buffer and keep adding to it until you hit a 0x0D 0x0A, then you can process that as a line.
2. Instead of using the asynchronous [SerialPort.DataRecieved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event, you could change your code around to using the synchronous [SerialPort.ReadLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which will read an entire line at a time.

This is obviously simplified, but it should work something like this:

```
public bool KeepRunning = true;
while(KeepRunning)
{
    string command = serialport.ReadLine();
    processCommand(command);
}
```

Where serialport is an already opened SerialPort object, and processCommand is some method that will handle an entire line.

Comment: I just noticed the `\r\n` right when you posted this. @user3357505 this is how you solve the problem you mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the baud rate will not give you the desired result you are looking for
. The SerialPort class (nor any class based on Stream which is what the class tries to emulate) guarantees the exact amount of data received will be the amount you requested. If you want 8 byte chunks you need to buffer the incoming data and every time you get 8 bytes worth of data you return the result.

You will need to put a layer to do your buffering between your reading of the serial port and your `File.AppendAllText` so you build up until you have 8 bytes of data then you write out to the file.

```
private byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
private int bufferOffset = 0;

private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    int totalBytesToRead = comport.BytesToRead;
    int totalBytesRead = 0;

    while (totalBytesToRead > totalBytesRead)
    {
        //Chooses the remaining size in the buffer or the remaining bytes available to read, whichever is smaller.
        var bytesToRead = Math.Min(buffer.Length - bufferOffset, totalBytesToRead - totalBytesRead);

        var bytesRead = comport.Read(buffer, bufferOffset, bytesToRead);

        bufferOffset += bytesRead;
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

        //If we have filled our buffer write it out to the file.
        if (bufferOffset == buffer.Length)
        {
            string timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
            File.AppendAllText(@"c:\file.txt", timestamp + "  " + ByteArrayToHexString(buffer) + "\n" + Environment.NewLine);
            bufferOffset = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is, sometimes HW send:
H1234V0   thats is just 7 bytes,     
and sometimes:
H1234V5678    thats is 10 bytes

Comment: @user3357505 in your example text your hex always ends with `OD OA` (aka: `\r\n`) is it garneted to always end the string with that?

Comment: yeah. always start with H and end with \r\n

Comment: @user3357505 see [Tremmors answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25253031/80274) then, the best thing to do is either loop till you see a `\r\n` or use `ReadLine`